# What is the term used to describe a discrete function which is non-zero at only 1 point, and zero everywhere else? Intended for a spatial domain.

Tags: functions, signal-processing, uniform-distribution, discrete-optimization

Please see the image below.

What is the formal term for the type of function shown below.

- One could describe it as a uniform distribution and the domain being x=5. But this is not elegant
- One could describe it as a logic signal at x=5, but this is not very accurate.

It is intended for a spatial domain. So if there is a grid, I would like to describe a function which is "a" at only one point in the grid, and "b" everywhere else.

Is a succinct term for this function?

[image: Example image of the type of function referred to in the question]

Comment: The [indicator function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\{5\}$ is what I would use.

Comment: It would improve your Question (and make it more precise!) to specify the domain intended for the function.  The image makes it seem that you have in mind a function defined only on integers(?).

Comment: Thank you, I think the Kronecker delta does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta):
$$
\delta_{5x} = \begin{cases}
1 \quad x = 5 \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

**Edit** in response to an edit in the question.

This will work for a grid: $\delta_{xy}$ makes sense when $x$ and $y$ are elements of any universe $S$ so you can write
$$
f_x(y) = (a-b)\delta_{xy} + b .
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is it.